# django rest framework : <Objectname: Objectname object> is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a customer model and an event model. event model refer to the customer. A customer has many events. My requirement is when I get the customer, I need the latest event object of the customer. When I call the customer Get API, it shows the following error,

> TypeError at /api/v1/customer
>
> is not JSON serializable

My Models

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    #some more fields to go
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


    def latest_event_name(self):
        """Return latest event """

        latest_event = self.customer_events.order_by('-event_date').last()
        return latest_event if latest_event else None



class Event(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    customer = models.ForeignKey(customer_models.Customer, db_index=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                 related_name='customer_events', null=True)
   #some more fields to go
```

serializer

```
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    latest_event_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: List the rest of the fields in `Event` - clearly one of them is preventing serialization.

Comment: Where are you trying to do the serialzing? If you get a `CustomerEvent` instance, what is it supposed to serialize into?

Comment: @shadow - Its the `latest_event_name` that isn't serializable since DRF has no idea how to serialize the queryset result

Comment: does `latest_event_name = EventSerializer(read_only=True)` do what you're looking for? (You'll need to write the event serializer)

Comment: If I use `code return latest_event.event_name if latest_event else None ` in model,` 'latest_event_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField()' ` will work in serializer. It will return the event name. But I need the full event object.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using Events in

```
def latest_event_name(self): ...
```

you'll have to create a serializer for the Event model, because that method returns an instance of the model Event.

I think that, if you just return the id of the Event as a str, you will not have that problem, so you wouldn't have to create a seralizer for the Event model.

Comment: I need the full event object

Answer (score 0):

Anyway now fixed the issue by the following method.

```
def latest_event(self):
latest_event = self.customer_events.order_by('-event_date').last()
eventDict = None
if latest_event:
    eventDict = {"event_id": latest_event.id, "event_name": latest_event.event_name}
return eventDict
```

Not sure whether its the correct method or not.

Comment: Of course you can do that, basically you are serializing the object by hand